# How can I optimize this working TAT query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been tasked with creating a TAT report that does not include weekends and holidays. The purpose of this post is to determine whether the solution I have made can be better optimized, by being improved upon or with yet another alternative.

When I initially set about this task, I thought of joining to a Dates table, but that seemed problematic because if I have a data set like this:

```
create table #example (ID varchar(50), startdate datetime2, enddate datetime2)

insert into #example
values
('4CF662A3-57EE-446B-9FC3-3F105219F253',      '2021-05-07 21:45:00.000',              '2021-05-15 08:46:32.000')
,('8B58294D-C20E-4E87-8B9C-186EFB3DCF19',      '2021-04-29 08:52:00.000',              '2021-05-06 20:02:58.000')
,('6177A53C-B285-4087-9F03-BF3324992DEE',      '2021-05-20 10:47:00.000',              '2021-05-27 22:05:30.000')
,('26E3A73E-9D5A-472C-890A-57D51B038C79',      '2021-05-04 20:24:00.000',              '2021-05-12 09:11:47.000')
,('ECC7DB03-A2D9-4D03-AC8D-47B5204C5512',      '2021-05-13 20:24:00.000',              '2021-05-21 10:29:03.000')
,('0A673471-CA22-4AA5-8024-EEF7CEBA8A0D',      '2021-05-10 20:24:00.000',              '2021-05-18 11:03:41.000')
,('27ADB272-A9E0-42ED-AE3C-E42F051C60DF',      '2021-05-03 20:06:00.000',              '2021-05-11 10:59:29.000')
,('5B9D97EC-A994-45E3-BB18-E583C9702389',      '2021-05-11 18:39:00.000',              '2021-05-19 09:56:18.000')
,('DE88A793-4F1C-479D-BB28-4245D9D30606',      '2021-05-10 20:07:00.000',              '2021-05-18 11:48:17.000')
,('42962CBB-79AF-44CB-8EB9-565A75EEA565',      '2021-04-26 21:35:00.000',              '2021-05-04 13:16:25.000')
,('62A980BF-D6B5-47F3-A671-D7F3DE046747',      '2021-05-20 18:08:00.000',              '2021-05-28 10:06:56.000')
,('E1D89979-7D77-4D63-983E-8127A1CB81FA',      '2021-05-18 20:28:00.000',              '2021-05-26 12:27:32.000')
,('D3D923AC-21E0-401E-A9DB-7BE1BE87A6B1',      '2021-05-13 19:56:00.000',              '2021-05-21 11:55:22.000')
,('364F5BF9-55A3-430E-9F41-F3EB41D30633',      '2021-05-13 19:58:00.000',              '2021-05-21 12:09:43.000')

select * from #example drop table #example
```

Then joining to a Date table would simply tell me whether the date joined on is a Work day, holiday, etc.

(Note: I have seen some attempts to join create a Business TAT report by joining to a Date table, but they seemed to not be as accurate as desired or had strange issues. I myself did not explore this option in too much depth for these reasons.)

I next looked at a scalar UDF using a loop. I was inspired mainly by this article: https://anyonconsulting.com/business_intelligence/how-to-count-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates-which-exclude-weekends-and-holidays/. This is the query I ultimately developed:

```
declare @DateFrom as datetime2 = '2021-05-17 19:06:00.000';
declare @DateTo as datetime2 = '2021-05-31 17:59:51.000';

-- Switches things around
if @DateFrom > @DateTo
    begin
        declare
            @T datetime2 = @DateTo
            , @F datetime2 = @DateFrom
        select @DateFrom = @T
            , @DateTo = @F
    end

declare @temptable table (
CalendarDate datetime2 not null primary key
, DayID as (datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]))
, isHoliday as 
    (case  
        -- New Year's Day, Observed 1st Day of Year
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 1  and day([CalendarDate]) = 1 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) in (2,3,4,5,6) then 1 --New Year’s Day
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 12  and day([CalendarDate]) = 31 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) =6 then 1 --New Year’s Day
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 1  and day([CalendarDate]) = 2 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) =2 then 1 --New Year’s Day

        -- Martin Luther King Jr. Day, Observed 3rd Monday of January
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 1  and day([CalendarDate]) >= 15 and day([CalendarDate]) <= 21 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) = 2 then 1

        -- Presidents' Day, Officially Washington’s Birthday, Observed 3rd Monday of February
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 2  and day([CalendarDate]) >= 15 and day([CalendarDate]) <= 21 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) = 2 then 1 

        -- Memorial Day, Observed Last Monday of May
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 5  and day([CalendarDate]) >= 25 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) = 2 then 1

        -- Independence Day, July 4th
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 7  and day([CalendarDate]) = 4 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) IN (2,3,4,5,6) then 1
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 7  and day([CalendarDate]) = 3 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) =6 then 1
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 7  and day([CalendarDate]) = 5 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) =2 then 1

        -- Labor Day, Observed First Monday of September
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 9  and day([CalendarDate]) <= 7 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) = 2 then 1

        -- Thanksgiving Day, Observed Fourth Thursday of November
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 11 and day([CalendarDate]) >= 22 and day([CalendarDate]) <= 28 AND datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) = 5 then 1

        -- Christmas Day, Observed 25th of December
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 12 and day([CalendarDate]) = 25 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) IN (2,3,4,5,6) then 1
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 12 and day([CalendarDate]) = 24 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) =6 then 1
        when month([CalendarDate]) = 12 and day([CalendarDate]) = 26 and datepart(weekday,[CalendarDate]) =2 then 1

        else 0

    end))

-- Fill the Calendar table
declare @D datetime2 = @DateFrom
while @D <= @DateTo
begin
   insert into @temptable (CalendarDate)
      select @D
   set @D = dateadd(hour, 1, @D)
end

declare
    @Count as int = 0
    , @Date as datetime2 = @DateFrom
while 
    @Date <= @DateTo
begin
    if ((datepart(weekday, @Date) in (1, 7))
        or exists
            (select *
            from @temptable
            where CalendarDate = @Date
                and isHoliday = 1
                and (DayID <> 7 or DayID <> 1)))
        begin
            select @Count = @Count + 1
        end

    select @Date = dateadd(hour, 1, @Date)
end

select convert(decimal(38,2) , (datediff(hour, @DateFrom, @DateTo) - (@Count)) / 24.0) as [TAT]
```

This script, when put into a function, is pretty accurate but suffered from slow performance. On a test set of 43,057 rows it took 1 minute 19 seconds (getting this to perform well is important for me since the query already takes long enough as is). Due to the poor performance, I started thinking about alternative ways to do this. One that I worked on for a bit, and came to appreciate, was this: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calculating-work-days. Unfortunately, however, it wasn't accurate enough for me, as I want a decimal days TAT (so I want a TAT of 4.68 as opposed to 5).

I then started thinking about some kind of set-based function, inspired by this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-joy-of-numbers as well as Itzik Ben-Gan's T-SQL Querying, pp. 216-218 on populating numbers tables. After some experimenting, I got this query:

```
declare 
    @TotalTimeDiff int
    , @low int
    , @DateFrom datetime2
    , @DateTo datetime2;

set @DateFrom = '2021-05-17 19:06:00.000';
set @DateTo = '2021-05-31 17:59:51.000';

set @low = 1;
set @TotalTimeDiff = (datediff(hour, @DateFrom, @DateTo))

;with 
    L0 as (select C from (values(1),(1)) as D(c)),
    L1 as (select 1 as c from L0 as A cross join L0 as B),
    L2 as (select 1 as c from L1 as A cross join L1 as B),
    L3 as (select 1 as c from L2 as A cross join L2 as B),
    L4 as (select 1 as c from L3 as A cross join L3 as B),
    L5 as (select 1 as c from L4 as A cross join L4 as B), -- Up to 4,294,967,296 rows
    
    Nums as (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as rownum from L5),

    Times as (select top (@TotalTimeDiff) @low + rownum - 1 as n from Nums)

select
    [TAT] = isnull(((count(BusinessHours.n) - sum(BusinessHours.NonBusinessHours)) / 24.0), datediff(minute, @DateFrom, @DateTo) / 1440.0)
from (
    select tms.n
    , [NonBusinessHours] = 
        case 
            when datename(dw, dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) in ('Sunday', 'Saturday') then 1
            
            -- New Year's Day, Observed 1st Day of Year
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 1  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 1 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) in (2,3,4,5,6) then 1 --    New Year’s Day
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 12  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 31 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) =6 then 1 --New Year’s    Day
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 1  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 2 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) =2 then 1 --New Year’s  Day

            -- Martin Luther King Jr. Day, Observed 3rd Monday of January
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 1  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) >= 15 and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) <= 21 and datepart(weekday,dateadd (hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 2 then 1

            -- Presidents' Day, Officially Washington’s Birthday, Observed 3rd Monday of February
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 2  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) >= 15 and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) <= 21 and datepart(weekday,dateadd (hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 2 then 1 

            -- Memorial Day, Observed Last Monday of May
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 5  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) >= 25 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 2 then 1

            -- Independence Day, July 4th
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 7  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 4 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) IN (2,3,4,5,6) then 1
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 7  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 3 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) =6 then 1
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 7  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 5 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) =2 then 1

            -- Labor Day, Observed First Monday of September
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 9  and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) <= 7 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 2 then 1 

            -- Thanksgiving Day, Observed Fourth Thursday of November
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 11 and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) >= 22 and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) <= 28 AND datepart(weekday,dateadd (hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 5 then 1

            -- Christmas Day, Observed 25th of December
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 12 and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 25 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) IN (2,3,4,5,6) then 1
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 12 and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 24 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) =6 then 1
            when month(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 12 and day(dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) = 26 and datepart(weekday,dateadd(hour, tms.n, @DateFrom)) =2 then 1

        else 0 end
    from Times as tms) as [BusinessHours]
```

This query, after being converted to a scalar UDF, calculated business TAT for those 43,057 rows in 17 seconds, a clear improvement over the looping query. (This is all SQL Server 2017, by the way.)

First, I'm wondering if this last solution is what one could consider a "set-based" solution. It seems to be more set-based than the clearly procedural/iterative loop, but it's not calculating TAT as derived from the data set itself, but from itemized input from the table (@DateFrom and @DateTo). I would think a purely "set-based" solution would mean using sophisticated join logic from the data-set itself to a Date table. This function is set-based, however, in the sense that once the function itself is running it does not go through a loop, determining each hour one-by-one, but rather given a list of numbers pushes through the itemized hours in the relevant date/time set and whether each is a working hour or not.

Second, does anyone know of a way that this could be further improved upon? Or an alternative approach, to this level of accuracy (classifying each hour in between two dates as a business hour or not)? Something that performs faster than this?

Thanks. If this is posted inappropriately (it does seem a bit less specific than is desired here) I would appreciate redirection so I can post this there. I am mainly trying to crowdsource this function a bit to see how far it can go, as well as put this function out there as it was fun to converge on after looking at multiple solutions.

Comment: Itzik's tally function works well in a lot of cases, but is probably going to be slow here because there are so many ifs and buts. Confused about why you can't join a proper `Dates` table, just filter to only work days?

Comment: A Dates table would be joined on either my start or end points. Say I have a start of 2021-05-26 09:30 and an end of 2021-06-02 09:30. If I join on the end point to the Dates table (at the level of day), all I know is that June 2 may or may not be a working day. But I want to know which all, if any, of the days between May 26 and June 2 are working days. In this case, May 29, 30, and 31 are not working days. So how does joining to a Dates table tell me to exclude those from the TAT? Well, this is possible with some joins but so far I have not been able to make a completely accurate query.

Comment: It's just a simple interval check. Something like this `select t.SomeId, count(case when d.IsWorkday then 1 end) as NumWorkDays from yourtable t join dates d on t.EndDateTime > d.StartDate and t.StartDateTime < d.NextDate group by t.SomeId`

Comment: Right. This does work most of the time, but, I always seem to run into problems when the TAT is very small and the StartDtTm or EndDtTm lands on an excluded day. For example, StartDtTm of 2021-01-29 19:02 and EndDtTm of 2021-01-31 13:21:32. The TAT with that last function I have is 0.17 days. With the joining to a Dates table, I get -0.236806 because `datediff(mm, StartDtTm, EndDtTm) / 1440.0 - count(d.ExcludedFromTAT)` is a number less than zero (note my setup is slightly different than yours). If I want to capture that 0.17, how can I do that if my Dates table is at the level of day?

Comment: Another example is StartDtTm of 2021-03-06 10:28:00 and EndDtTm of 2021-03-06 16:10:36. That's a Saturday, so I get the `datediff(mm, StartDtTm, EndDtTm) / 1440.0` as 0.24 and then subtract 1, the number of non-work days that I got from my Dates table, with a result of -0.76. What I really want, in this case, is 0.0 (all of it took place on a Saturday). This is different than the last example too because that previous one did include some work hours, whereas this one includes no work hours.

Comment: I have thought of a way to get accurate TAT for cases where both StartDtTm and EndDtTm land on an excluded day (the same day or adjacent days) - simply list as 0.0. In cases where there are some work hours, however, I am not sure what can be done. Those are the minority and could be listed as 0.0 as well, but if you have any ideas that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So when you do a calculation based on that, you need to take the later start and the earlier end, something like `DATEDIFF(mm, CASE WHEN t.StartDateTime > d.Date THEN t.StartDateTime ELSE d.StartDate END, CASE WHEN t.EndDateTime < d.NextDate THEN t.EndDateTime ELSE d.NextDate END)` which admittedly looks complex, but you could put it in a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` and reuse it elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Charlieface, I did come up with a fairly accurate solution using just a Date table. Since I only made that solution on Production data, I am not posting it here, but it is possible. That being said, I was only able to ameliorate the problems with that kind of solution to some extent. The questions that arose were:

- What if something was completed on a Sunday?
- How do we know what days were actually worked?
- Did they work Saturday as well?

This solution did perform faster than my Second one above (about 5-7 seconds faster), however, given the little inaccuracies, I opted in favor of the Second one above. Hopefully this post can help guide others who are looking to calculate business TAT according to their own custom business logic.